# How to avoid unhandled exception in boolean method?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am trying to use `ReflectiveOperationException` in this method but I am getting `UnhandeledException` error but when I change my Exception with

```
throw new ReflectiveOperationException("izuoizoiuz");
```

than there no error. How can I avoid this `UnhandeledException` error.

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(Object bean, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
    try {
        if (Assert.isNull(bean)) {
            logger.info(EXC_MSG_BEAN_NULL, bean.toString());
        }

        String dependentFieldActualValue;
        dependentFieldActualValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, dependentField);
        boolean isActualEqual = stringEquals(dependentFieldValue, dependentFieldActualValue);

        if (isActualEqual == ifInequalThenValidate) {
            return true; // The condition is not met => Do not validate at all.
        }
        return isTargetValid(bean, ctx); // Perform the actual validation on the target field
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        logger.info("Necessary attributes can't be accessed: {}");
        throw new ReflectiveOperationException("izuoizoiuz");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReflectiveOperationException` is a "checked" exception. That means that your method needs to declare that it can throw it:

```
public boolean isValid(Object bean, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
```

Also, note that you don’t have to create a new ReflectiveOperationException. You can `throw e` to rethrow the original, keeping its stack trace, etc.

Comment: This is only possible where the superclass declares that it throws `ReflectiveOperationException` (or a superclass) too. Otherwise, you have to rethrow an unchecked exception (or otherwise handle the exception).

Answer (score 1):

Its a Checked exception and either needs to be declared(with throws) with method signature or needs to explicitly thrown like you are doing.

Its enforced by compiler.
You can convert checked exceptions into unchecked exceptions by using a wrapper exception.

```
public Object loadTest (int objId)
{

 try {

    Connection c = Database.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement(OBJECT_QUERY);
    query.setInt(1, objId);
    ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
    ...
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot query object " + objId, ex);
 }
}
```